# Sync Hub and Spoke model with SQL Server Express on server and clients

Tags: sql-server, wcf, sql-server-2008, synchronization, wcf-data-services

I have been researching on how to sync clients SQL Server Express to a central SQL Server Express. At first I looked at Replication but the only issue is that replication is not supported if the central server is SQL Server 2008 Express.

I had to find another solution; I looked at the sync framework with WCF. At first it looked promising but the more I researched it the more I realized that documentation was extremely poor as well there were no samples for syncing SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2008 using Visual Studio 2010 project. I did find a few samples on blogs but could never get them to work. I am coming to the conclusion that sync framework is not the way to go because of the lack of support and samples for the product.

I am now looking into a custom solution which will require a great deal more coding and testing.

I was just wondering if anyone has had to sync production server SQL Server Express with clients also running SQL Server Express. How did you accomplish this and what technology did you use?

I'm stuck, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're referring to the VS Local Database Cache project item, yes, it doesnt support SQL Express as a client.

if you're willing to hand code, the docs has a tutorial, see: [Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928700)

other samples you can take a look at:
[Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express 2-Tier](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-a9752fac)

[Database Sync:SQL Server and SQL Express N-Tier with WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Database-SyncSQL-Server-e97d1208)